# Tricontour plot doesn't make density zones

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, kernel-density

I have 3 variables that are 1D arrays : x, z, y. I want to plot a contour graph but i dont have the relation between z= f(x,y) so im using tricontour plot. I get this figure, and i can see that for the graphs in the letf side we could get some contour lines but i obtain a kind of disorder lines.

[image: chart1]

I already try to smooth , interpolate and extrapolate my point withou a succesfull results.
Here is the comand:

```
ax4.tricontour(df.FPER,  df.KRII, df.kge_amont, limit, levels=5 , linewidths=0.5, linestyles= 'solid')
```

Can someone help me to make it cleaner making some kind of density contour.

I try to find how to make a plot like in this image:

[image: chart2]

but i get the opposite.

Comment: I have 3 variables that are 1D arrays : x, z, y.  meaning :  x_array, y_array, z_array ??

Comment: Thanks for the answers,

@JohanC,  I try with  sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='FPER',  y='KRII',  hue='kge_amont') but it gives me an error because it doesn't follow a normal density.  If I use 'weights' it only gives me a contour of x and y but doesn't integrate the z values. 

Pippo1980, yes  x_array, y_arrays, z_arrays...

Answer (score -1):

I think I find an answer,

```
N=10

nx = 10*int(np.sqrt(N))
xg = np.linspace(df.FPER.min(), df.FPER.max(), nx)
yg = np.linspace(df.Hsol.min(), df.Hsol.max(), nx)
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(xg, yg)
ctr_f = griddata((df.FPER, df.Hsol), df.kge_amont, (xgrid, ygrid), method='linear')
fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1) 
ax.contourf(xgrid, ygrid, ctr_f, cmap=cm.coolwarm, cbar=True, levels=5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide an explanation of your code to help others better understand it.